# how to add tool tip in yii-chartjs extension

Tags: yii, charts, yii-extensions, chart.js

I am using [yii-chartjs](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-chartjs/) extension in my project. it works fine, but i want to add tool tip in  Doughnut Chart. or is there any way to add labels in the chart.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that by replace the chart.js with [this](https://github.com/Regaddi/Chart.js/blob/tooltips/Chart.js) file

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Chart.js Library has tooltip support for any one of it's charts. The closest thing they provide is labels.